# Conformal dilation map preserving Gauss curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

In strict isometric mappings there is no change in line element lengths ***and*** angles between them as required by the  Egregium theorem.

One of the two requirements can be relaxed in what we may refer to as  "semi-isometry". The converse of Egregium theorem ( If K is constant then there would  isometry)  is not true.

The Sine-Gordon  differential equation preserves lengths along parametric lines with constant (negative) Gauss curvature K among mappings but allows varying the inter fiber angles (shear) $\omega$ among differential line elements to obey a pde in  $\mathbb R^3$ :

$$\dfrac{\partial ^2 \omega}{\partial u \partial v}=\sin \omega \tag1 $$

[Designing Cylinders_Pinkall](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ulrich_Pinkall)

[Chebyshev Net](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Negative_curvature,_surface_of) (Equations 1,2 and 3).

If we interchange dilation and shear instead from the above.

What is the resulting partial differential equation of conformal mappings among differential surface elements enclosed between line elements  $(du,dv)$  of the parameterized surface $ (x,y,z)= [f(u),g(v)], $ ( preserving angles and Gauss curvature K ),but allowing line element dilation?

It is possible  to solve and visualize for easier to solve surfaces of revolution when $(u,v)$ lines orthogonal as Loxodromes keeping angle between fibers constant. For $ K>0,K<0 $ and ode of meridian tangent slope $\phi$ that satisfies the above condition was found after posing the question here to be:

$$\phi^{''}\cot \phi -\phi'^2 =  K {\cos^2 \alpha} \tag2 $$

Numerical solution defines shapes as below:

[image]

However unable to find any text/classical references so far for a general PDE. I had expected it to be available since the Chebyshev net counterpart part is well known.

I would attempt to improve the above images retaining only the lines and removing the surface that may perhaps be visually little more more convincing.

We have in constant $(K = \pm 1/a^2)$ conservation mappings.....

fixed lengths, fixed angles is full isometry. Egregium theorem

fixed lengths, variable angle ChebychevNet/Sine Gordon Equn

fixed angles, variable line lengths ??

Hope my question is clear. Request please point to the relevant literature.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What is a surface element?

Comment: I have edited hopefully explaiing background for my question. Please comment if it needs some  further explanation.

Comment: The "mapping" "defined" by the sine-Gordon equation does not preserve "lengths". Do you mean preserving lengths only along two directions? It also does not preserve Gaussian curvature... (I am not sure how you get from the EoM article to a map that preserves Gauss curvature)

Comment: Yes, only  length of line elements.along u,v parameter directions ( and angles )   are conserved  in all isometric mappings.By Egregim thm K is also conserved.